# Image processing functions

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
init_filename = 'vtkfile';         % name of the VTK file to be processed
ext_stack = '.vtk';                     % VTK file extension
ext_stl = '.stl';                       % extension of the output file. STL - stereolitography format, stores a list of 3-node triangular elements that comprise an object's surface mesh
ext_mat = '.mat';                       % extension of the outpit file that stores geometry information of individual objects

vtk_filename = strcat('vtk\',init_filename, ext_stack);

% Check if VTK file with user specified filename exists
if exist(vtk_filename,'file') == 0
    disp('No such file');
    return
end

V = readvtk(vtk_filename)/255;         % writes (and converts to binary) the information from the VTK file into 3D matrix
%% 

dims = size(V)                        % dimensions of the input 3D matrix
%% 

cc = bwlabel(V,6);                  % identifies number of individual objects and stores their voxel coordinates in the 3D matrix (muCT data)
%save('full_setup.mat','-v7.3');
```

I have this program, when I run it I get this error message:

> Undefined function 'bwlabel' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

I use matlab 2014b with image processing tools included

Can you please help?

Comment: `bwlabel` works only on 2D matrices. Perhaps you're looking for [`bwlabeln`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabeln.html) which works in `n` dimensions.